# C# convert DateTime from one format to another

Tags: c#

I thought this would be a really simple, and i've tried to google it and I keep getting the exception `String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.`

This is my value `"2013-10-21T14:10:49"` this is what I want to convert it into `10/21/2013 10:49`

```
string sample = "2013-10-21T14:10:49";
DateTime date31 = DateTime.ParseExact(sample, "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Comment: parse exact should match your datetime format.  it clearly does not

Comment: Obviously, you format string does not match the sample data.

Comment: What month is 2013 again?  I can only remember the first twelve off hand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your string appears to be in format of "Xml-serialized". So it is the job of `XmlConvert`.

```
string sample = "2013-10-21T14:10:49";
string converted = XmlConvert.ToDateTime(sample, XmlDateTimeSerializationMode.Unspecified)
     .ToString("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Comment: Bingo, impressive how you knew it was XML

Comment: @Mike `T` format is used by `XmlSerializer`s no other uses it.

Answer (score 3):

When you write [`DateTime.ParseExact(sample, "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm", ...)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss.aspx), you are saying that `sample` is in the format `MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm`. Since it is not, it throws an exception.

It's important to know that a `DateTime` does not have any format associated with it. It's only when you convert it to or from a string that format can come into play. You should probably use something like this:

```
string sample = "2013-10-21T14:10:49";
DateTime date31 = DateTime.Parse(sample, System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
string date31string = date31.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
// date31string is "10/21/2013 14:10"
```

Instead of `ParseExact`, I used [`Parse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.parse.aspx), since the format is recognized by `Parse`, and I don't see much point in limiting what sort of formats it can accept to *only* that particular format.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need the `ParseExact` method, the `Parse` method is sufficient because it allows your date representation. See [DateTime - The string to parse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.parse%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#StringToParse) for an overview of allowed input formats.

This means the following works:

```
string sample = "2013-10-21T14:10:49";
DateTime parsed = DateTime.Parse(sample);

Console.WriteLine(parsed.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss"));
```

And the result is:

```
10/21/2013 14:10:49
```